# About Google's Play API minimum level requirement

Tags: android, phonegap

I just released a new app using Phonegap. As I uploaded on Play store. I got this  warning info

> Google Play will require that new apps target at least Android 8.0
>   (API level 26) from August 1, 2018, and that app updates target
>   Android 8.0 from November 1, 2018.
>
> Every new Android version introduces changes that bring significant
>   security and performance improvements – and enhance the user
>   experience of Android overall. Some of these changes only apply to
>   apps that explicitly declare support through their targetSdkVersion
>   manifest attribute (also known as the target API level).

Well, I increased the API level to 26, and when I tried to install, it says "device not compatible". I checked my phones Android version, it was version 6.0. I was able to understand that API level 26 is version 8.

Question is - what do I do about this? How can I have my app for other version users?

Thank you.

Comment: What did you update in your application?

Comment: Did you update your targetSdkVersion or your minimumSdkVersion? You should update the target.

Comment: It was a new application with android-targetSdkVersion set to 26. Do I need to set minimumSdkversion, will it solve the issue?

Comment: No.  Minimum-sdk is the lowest supported.  That does not need to be changed, its ok (even expected) to support older devices

Comment: Set your minimum to the minimum SDK version you need to support. For version 6.0 it would be API Level 23 (but you'd likely want to go lower to support more devices).

Comment: I did not add minimumSdkversion, it was not added by Phonegap. Let me add and try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two relevant settings here.  Target SDK version is what Google is looking for.  That's the SDK that your app is optimized for.  Min SDK version is the lowest version your app will run on (there is also a max SDK version, but I have never had a use for it).  You'll need to update your Config.xml file with the min sdk version tag.  You'll have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "com.phonegap.example"
    versionCode = "10"
    version     = "1.0.0" >

  <name>PhoneGap Example</name>
  <description>
      An example for phonegap build docs.
  </description>
  <author href="https://build.phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
      wildabeast
  </author>

  <!-- all platforms -->
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.0.0" />
  <preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />

  <!-- Android only -->
  <preference name="android-build-tool" value="ant|gradle" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26" />
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
</widget>
```

The key line is near the bottom:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" />
```

You can read more here: http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/preferences/#android-minSdkVersion